# 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Id can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used devide in gem and now I made Sign up&Log in pages.
When I wrote my id and email address in my app,blowser told me 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:  Id can't be blank.Of course,I surely wrote id,so I don't know why.
Is this blowser error?
I wrote in home_controller,

```css
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :find_user, only: [:index]

  def index
    # @id = params[:id]
    # @email = params[:email]
    if id == @user.id  && email == @user.email
      render :text =>   "sucsess"
    else
      render :text =>   "fail"
    end
  end

  def create
    id = params[:id]
    email = params[:email]
    @user = UserData.new(user_params)
    @user.save

    unless  userData.save
     @error_message = errors.full_messages.compact
    end
  end

   private

   def find_user
     user = User.find(params[:id])
     if current_user.id != user.id
       redirect_to root_path
     end
   end
end
```

in users.rb

```css
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  validates :id, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

         
end
```

in migration file

```css
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```css
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'notes/new'

  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/create'
  

  namespace :home, default: {format: :json} do
    resources :index, only: :create
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need to set `id` when creating a user. It should be automatically generated.

Comment: thx,I delete id = params[:id] in create action,but I got same error.

Comment: Are you able to create User in rails console? without providing id.

Comment: Also, please show `user_params`

Answer (score 2):

Validation runs before creation. So the `id` will have no chance of being created before you save.

Remove this
`validates :id, presence: true`

and don't set the `id` manually on the `create` action.

Comment: thx,ur answer.I deleted id = params[:id] & validates :id, presence: true,and rails s again.But I got error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index
Couldn't find User with 'id'=.It is natural because I deleted id.What should I do to work my app well?

Comment: I don't think there's an `id` for your `index` action now. So `params[:id]` is currently `nil`. The error is in `find_user`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove below line from model, as ID is auto generated field.

**validates :id, presence: true**

Update create action in controller file as below,

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
  unless  @user.save
    @error_message = errors.full_messages.compact
  end
end
```

Replace "UserData" with "User" which is the model name as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove below line

```
validates :id, presence: true
```

as id is create automatically by rails and no need to validate it.

And
In your controller, change private method code:

```
def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) #replace user to @user
   if current_user.id != user.id
   redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```